# Calling recursiviley a function depending on number of args in python

Tags: python, function, recursion

I have a function which takes two parameters and perform a binary operation:

```
def foo(arg1,arg2):
    return operation(arg1,arg2)
```

I need to generalize this function such that if three args are passed it returns `operation(arg1,operation(arg2,arg3))`, if four are provided `operation(arg1,operation(arg2,operation(arg3,arg4)))` and so on. Is it possible to do that in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and in fact it's built into the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

```py
import functools

def operation(a,b):
    return a + b

# returns 15
functools.reduce(operation, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

If you'd like, you can combine this with varargs mentioned in Nick's answer:

```py
import functools

def operation(a,b):
    return a + b

def foo(*args):
    return functools.reduce(operation, args)

# returns 15
foo(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Comment: If OP doesn't mind using libraries this is definitely simpler.

Comment: I would accept both of your answers, but I can accept only one. This solved my problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the [`*args`](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#id14) form of declaring a function; check if the length of the arguments is 2 and if so return the value of the operation, otherwise return the value of the operation of the first argument with `foo` of the remaining arguments:

```py
def operation(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2

def foo(*args):
    if (len(args) == 2):
        return operation(*args)
    return operation(args[0], foo(*args[1:]))

print(foo(1, 3))
print(foo(2, 3, 5))
print(foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
```

Output:

```
4
10
28
```

Note you may also want to check if 0 or 1 arguments are passed to prevent "index out of range" errors. For 1 argument you could just return the input value e.g.

```py
if (len(args) == 1):
    return args[0]
```

As pointed out by @wallefan in the comments, there is a standard library function for this: [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools%20reduce#functools.reduce). You can use that like this:

```py
from functools import reduce

print(reduce(operation, (1, 3)))
print(reduce(operation, (2, 3, 5)))
print(reduce(operation, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)))
```

The output is the same as the `foo` function above.

Comment: A `if len(args) == 1: return args[0]` could be added to the function `foo`, if we the mapping is defined also for single arguments.

Comment: It would also be good to mention that there is a standard library function for this: [functools.reduce()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis agreed - I had put in a note about that but it's better with code